Looking for a movie in which a woman tries to commit suicide by taking pills
I'm looking for a movie I saw like 7-8 years ago (maybe less, maybe more), so I don't remember much. Just this one scene: 
It's night. A woman buys some pills (probably antidepressants or sleeping pills), then goes to sit in her car in the parking lot. She then tries to commit suicide by taking all those pills. Shortly after, she loses consciousness. A young boy, about 10-12 years I think and probably black, finds her like that. At first he tries to wake her up, but when that fails, he just steals money from her purse.
I'm not sure I remember the details correctly though. I think the woman is played by Julianne Moore, but don't count on that, it probably is not true. I tried googling things like "Julianne Moore movie suicide" and such, but I did not find anything. I even looked Moore's movies up on IMDB, but without any satisfying results. If I had to guess, I'd say this movie is from USA, and was made around 2000. Movie's genre might be drama.
It also is possible that this scene I remember is actually a mix of more movies and/or I unknowingly added some details because they fit my fading memory of this scene.
Many thanks for any suggestions, which movie this might be from, or for an affirmation that movie with described scene doesn't actually exists.

You're describing a scene from Magnolia (1999).

[Linda (played by Julianne Moore)] drives to a vacant parking lot and washes down handfuls of prescription medicine with alcohol. Dixon [an African-American kid played by Emmanuel L. Johnson] finds Linda in her car, near death, and calls an ambulance after taking money from her purse.

Here's the trailer:




Dammit, for some reason I was sure it was not Magnolia. Well, thanks anyway, I can now sleep in peace.
